# Does the standard Html.DisplayTextFor() no HTML encoding?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, xss

We are currently dealing with some XSS issues on one of our ASP.NET MVC projects. I found two issues - the first one has to do with our request validation pattern. The attacker could now use this security hole to drop some bad content in our database.

The second issue is how we display this content and we use the Html.DisplayTextFor method and it seems to be "broken".

Just create a new MVC 3 WebApp, put this in the HomeController:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "<SCRIPT/XSS SRC=\"htpp://ha.ckers.org/css.js\">";

        User foo = new User();
        foo.Name = "<SCRIPT/XSS SRC=\"htpp://ha.ckers.org/css.js\">";

        return View(bla);
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }
}

public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The View:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name) <br/> ||| <-- will be encoded

@Html.Encode(ViewBag.Message)<br/> ||| <-- will be double encoded

@Model.Name <br/> ||| <-- will be encoded 

@Html.DisplayTextFor(m => m.Name) <-- no encoding
<br/> |||
```

Output of the DisplayTextFor will be the whole string `<script xss="" src="htpp://ha.ckers.org/css.js">`

Question is: Bug, feature or am I using it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Html.DisplayTextFor` is really for interacting with the `[DisplayFormat]` attribute ([see MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute.aspx)).

<strike>So if you're using it with unsafe values, you have to be aware of this and use `[DisplayFormat(HtmlEncode = true)]` on your property.</strike>

Edit: Looks like the HtmlEncode property isn't actually enforced by DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider (and DisplayTextFor).

Comment: So if I just want to output simple strings, which may contain bad values (and I don´t want to decorate all my properties with the DisplayFormat attribute), I should use just @Model.Name instead of the DisplayTextFor? Is it possible to override the default behaviour for the base types (string/int/double/...)?

Comment: Correct, `@Model.Name` is best for simple cases. For the base types, you can still call `ToString()` explicitly and specify a format or a formatprovider, e.g. `@Model.Number.ToString("N")`

Comment: Any idea why the value with DisplayTextFor is still not encoded when I use the [DisplayFormat(HtmlEncode = true)] Attribute? I just put it on the "Name" property in my model. Do I need anything else?

Comment: I apologize. I looked at the source on codeplex and it doesn't look like it fully uses the HtmlEncode property. I made a bad assumption - the MVC and DataAnnotation libraries don't always match up 100%.