# MvcHtmlString.ToHtmlString() not encoding HTML?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, xss

Related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9790557/does-the-standard-html-displaytextfor-no-html-encoding) I play around with XSS issues in my ASP.NET MVC project and I´m confused with the MvcHtmlSTring.ToHtmlString() method. From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.mvchtmlstring.tohtmlstring.aspx) "Returns an HTML-encoded string that represents the current object.", but it doesn´t work in my case:

```
    var mvcHtmlString = MvcHtmlString.Create("<SCRIPT/XSS SRC=\"htpp://ha.ckers.org/css.js\">").ToHtmlString();

    var encoded = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("<SCRIPT/XSS SRC=\"htpp://ha.ckers.org/css.js\">");
```

Output of mvcHtmlString

```
<SCRIPT/XSS SRC="htpp://ha.ckers.org/css.js">
```

Output of encoded <-- this is the behaviour I would suspect!

```
&lt;SCRIPT/XSS SRC=&quot;htpp://ha.ckers.org/css.js&quot;&gt;
```

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[MvcHtmlString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.mvchtmlstring.aspx) (or [HtmlString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.htmlstring.aspx), or anything that implements [IHtmlString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihtmlstring.aspx)) is for strings that should be emitted as HTML verbatim - i.e. by making that an MvcHtmlString you're telling it that you actually want those HTML tags.

The difference is when you emit the string into an ASP.NET page using `<%: .. %>` (new in ASP.NET 4 or later). In that case the ASP.NET engine will automatically HtmlEncode regular strings for you (or anything that doesn't implement IHtmlString) whereas the MvcHtmlString will be emitted into the page verbatim / unencoded.

i.e. I think the documentation is wrong. There's a [connect ticket](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/595790/system-web-htmlstring-constructor-functionality-does-not-match-framework-4-documentation) with the equivalent error in the HtmlString constructor documentation, which they did fix. (I thought I filed that :-/ maybe mine got closed as a duplicate of someone else's?) I didn't notice the MvcHtmlString documentation was wrong too.

Comment: If it´s just a documentation issue, whats the purpose of the ToHtmlString methode? From my example: There is no difference between calling the "ToHtmlString()" method and the "ToString()" method - both will output the bad un-encoded HTML.

Comment: It's the method on the [IHtmlString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihtmlstring.aspx) interface. It really means "return HTML content to be inserted into the page" - i.e. this is what ASP.NET MVC 4 will call and emit the results without further encoding. I guess it's so you can do something different in other classes but you're right there's no difference here.

Answer (score 9):

The MSDN documentation is correct, but perhaps a bit confusing. The `MvcHtmlString` and `IHtmlString` interface are used to represent a string that has *already* been HTML encoded. MSDN says:

> Returns an HTML-encoded string that represents the current object.

The object you passed in to the `MvcHtmlString` object was already HTML-encoded, so both `.ToString()` and `.ToHtmlString()` merely return the object you passed in.

Please note that the MSDN docs do clearly state that:

> The ToHtmlString and ToString methods return the same value.

So why have all this? Two reasons:

1. In the Razor view engine and in ASP.NET Web Forms v4 an object that implements `IHtmlString` is written out as raw data. The view engines assume that the person creating the `IHtmlString` has already sanitized the data.
2. The `IHtmlString` has its own stringify method so that it need not have the same implementation as `ToString()`. While `ToHtmlString()` must return the HTML, you could easily imagine that `ToString()` might return some developer-friendly debug information.

Comment: IMO it's "Returns a string of HTML content": it's not necessarily an HTML-encoded string, and it's mentioning encoding here which was misleading to the OP. I do think there's room for improvement here - in particular the "same value" remark (which is only on the MvcHtmlString docs and not HtmlString) should clarify that this is the value used to construct the object untransformed.